# Pushing git repository to Xcode

Tags: macos, git, xcode4

Current setup:

Home iMac with Xcode project and hosting the git repository. MacBook for working away from home with project cloned through Xcode.

I am able to pull changes made on my iMac to the MacBook without a problem, its sending the changes I make on my MacBook back to the iMac which I'm having trouble with.

I make my edits and `File > Source Control > Commit` which works without error and `File > Source Control > Push` the files - no problem.

But, on my iMac I can't get to the edits, as soon as Xcode launches, the 'M' appears next to the edited files showing a change has been made (the one on my MacBook) and I cannot revert the change, the only thing I can do is commit the unedited file and 'revert' it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a "push" operation to a non-bare repository - something that is specifically recommended *against* in the Git documentation.

What happens is the push operation updates the repository behind the scenes, but *not* your working directory. So Git sees all the files changed on your laptop as "changed" back to their original state on the iMac. You can fix this, if you are **absolutely sure** that you do not have uncommitted work on the iMac, by doing a `git reset --hard master` (or whatever your branch name is).

A better solution is to create another repository on the iMac, that is a "bare" repository, which you will treat as your shared global repository. Each working directory would both pull from and push to the global repository, avoiding this problem.

Comment: Great answer, set up a bare repository and it is working as expected. Thank you.